# non-replicated column still trigger replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a few columns in a table that are added to my publication articles. 
When a change on a column that is not included in replication occurs, it still seems to update the msrepl_tran_version which i assume still assigns the row for replication.
Is this how SQL-Server works?
Is there a way to tell sql only to relicate rows when a colum that is included in the articles is changed and not when a non-replicated column is changed?

Comment: Please note that "SQL" is not a synonym for "SQL Server"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to avoid this aside from hacking the system-generated triggers and procedures (which is very, very, very strongly discouraged). I'd strongly encourage you to enter a bug/suggestion at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com) outlining this issue and how it is affecting your environment. There are [others](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/jeffrey_yao/archive/2008/09/07/wish-list-for-sql-server-replication.aspx) you may want to recruit in your cause as well.